# A Lie algebra associated to a symplectic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let  $(M,\omega)$  be  a  symplectic  manifold of  dimension $2n$ with the volume form $\omega^n.$

In this question we associate  a  Lie  algebra $L(M,\omega)$ to $(M,\omega)$. Then we are interested to know:

> 1) Does the Lie  structure of $L(M,\omega)$ depend on symplectic  structure $\omega$? At the other extreme can one prove that if two Lie  algebras $L(M,\omega)$ and $L(M,\omega')$ are isomorphic Lie  algebras, then there is  a  symplectomorphism $f:(M,\omega) \to (M,\omega')$?
>
> 2)In the  literature, are  there some  precise computation of $L(M,\omega)$ for  some symplectic manifolds  $(M,\omega)$? What can be said  about dimension of $L(M,\omega)$?

Here  is  the  Lie  algebra we are considering:

$$L(M,\omega)=E(M,\omega)/Z'(M,\omega)$$

where $$E(M,\omega)=\left\{ X\in \chi^{\infty}(M)\mid L_X \omega=(1/n)Div(X)\omega\right \}=\{X\in \chi^{\infty}(M)\mid L_X \omega=f\omega,\;\;\text{ for  some  }f\in C^{\infty}(M)\}$$

and $Z'(M,\omega)$ is the normalizer of $Z(M,\omega)=\{X\in \chi^{\infty}(M)\mid L_X \omega=0\}$   in $E(M,\omega)$.

Comment: Your question 1 is really two questions:  I read "Does the Lie structure depend on the symplectic structure" as the question whether $\forall \omega,\omega' : L(M,\omega) \cong L(M,\omega')$ holds and the question beginning with "in other words" asks whether the invariant $L(M,\omega)$ is enough to classify symplectic structures.

Comment: @JohannesHahn  Yes they in opposite  direction: If the  first part has positive answer, that is the Lie  structure  is  sensitive to $\omega$ then it is natural to ask the last  part, the  classification one. Right?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I think he means that an equivalent question must follow "in other words" (In English language), not a completely different question

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat  Ah yes. Thank you and

Comment: and thank @JohannesHahn  for your comments. I will come back soon to revise it.

Comment: It seems to me that your first space is what is called the "algebra of conformally symplectic vector fields" and the second one the ideal of symplectic vector fields. You can find some results on this in Avez-Lichenrowicz, Sur l'algèbre des automorphismes infinitésimaux d'une variété symplectique, Journal Differential Geometry 40 (1974).

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli  Very excellent comment. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli  But is  $Z$ the algebra of vector field with zero divergence, an Ideal? How is it an ideal?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi Sorry that "ideal" probably shouldn't be there...

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a little detail to the discussion above and since what I wrote was not clear:

$E(M,\omega)$ is, in [Lichnerowicz-Avez-Diaz Miranda](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214432088) (I forgot the third author in the above citation), the Lie algebra of infinitesimal conformal symplectic transformations (Paragraph 5).

$Z(M,\omega)$ is, in Lichnerowicz-Avez, the Lie algebra of symplectic vector fields (equivalently locally hamiltonian vector fields).

$Z^\prime(M,\omega)$ is the normalizer (in Lie algebras you use this term rather than idealizer) of $Z(M,\omega)$ inside $E(M,\omega)$, i.e. the set 
$\{X\in E(M,\omega)\, : [X,Y]\in Z(M,\omega)\,\forall Y\in Z(M,\omega)\}$.

At page 12 it is shown that $[E(M,\omega),E(M,\omega)]\subseteq Z(M,\omega)$;
therefore $Z^\prime(M,\omega)=E(M,\omega)$, if I am not wrong and/or confused by different terminology and notations.

(btw Proposition 2 of the mentioned paper may be of interest to you)

Comment: Thanks  a lot for  your  answer  and the  reference. In dimension $2$(n=1) $E(M,\omega)=\chi^{\infty}(M)$. But I think that $Z$ is not  an ideal in $E$. For example $y\partial_x -x\partial_y \in Z,\;\;x^2\partial_x \in E$ but their  Lie  braket is  $2xy\partial_x+x^2\partial_y $ is  not  in $Z$.

Comment: Thanks again for sharing such a very interesting paper. I will read it carefuly. But it is strange : It seems that there is a possible contradictory situation. The example in the previous example shows that $Z$ is not an ideal!.